# Как узнать из какой зависимости прилетел пакет?

Tags: java, maven

У меня в небольшом приложении порой бывает ошибка типа

Исключительная ситуация IOException при поиске jarFile [""] для fileName [/start.jsp] java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\user....\lib\spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jad ( Системе не удается найти указанный путь.)

После пересборки проекта ( mvn clean install) у меня проект запускается, но проблема в том, что я, насколько помню, нигде напрямую не добавляю spring. У меня вообще легаси проект с 6 джавой и чтобы там еще и 4 спринг использовать....

Так вот, есть ли быстрый способ узнать, из какой зависимости в моей pom пришел этот Spring?

P.S. В импортированных библиотеках ( в IDEA это под проектом есть External Libraries) там я вообще всё семейство SPRING нашел от AOP до jdbc

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=имя_интересующей_вас_зависимости`

Comment: Если пользуетесь Идеей, можете зажать Ctrl и навести курсор на пакет в import

Comment: @AlexeyR. прикол в том, что нет прямой зависимости типа import org.springframework.... в проекте, он откуда-то лезет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вам поможет построение полного дерева зависимостей:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: Спасибо, из 6 зависимостей лезло

Comment: Я тоже только изучаю java и уже офигиваю от этого :)